# Using toolbar search button and displaying results in a fragment

Tags: android

I am using the Android Navigation Drawer and a toolbar with a search icon. When the user presses the search icon I want to display a new fragment with the search results. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use FraggmentManager to replace the framelayout in activiy or show me your code implementation ....

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

 fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new SearchFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Apply this code in your `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`